React Native Expo Api Routes & Query optimization/organization
I have two pages for my react native expo project, using psql database. The first place is the 'search' page, which shows all the products (cards showing image, title, price, location). When clicking on a product card, a detailed product page shows (image, title, price, location, description, condition, etc.).
The second page is the users products page, where it shows only the products the user has posted (products with the logged in user as user_id), displaying each product as a card (showing only image, title, price), then clicking on a card brings it to a detailed product edit page, where they can edit all the details.
My confusion arises when making api routes and fetching too much or not enough data. Example products+api.ts queries all products columns from the products table, which is great when showing a products detailed page, but the cards (search page) only use data from 3-4 columns, not all hence I would be querying more data than needed. Additionally, the user might only click on only a few product cards, hence retrieving all columns for all products would not be necessary but only for the products that are clicked on. The products all have a product_id, so I'm thinking about using this to my advantage, just not sure how to organize it.
Second confusion is between the search page and users product page data; the user's product page cards show slightly less information than the search pages cards, would the same api route be used? The users product edit page also allows for editing of products, hence why I feel this would be different than the search pages detailed product page.
Overall, its a confusion between not enough/too many api routes and querying more information than needed but not querying enough and feeling restricted when needing to use it elsewhere. Any information or resources on this topic would be appreciated!
